# Тап срабатывает на View сверху

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

Использую `ViewController` для попапа.
Добавил тап для закрытия окна на основную `View`

```
let viewTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissSelf))
view.addGestureRecognizer(viewTap)


@objc func dismissSelf() {
    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Как отключить срабатывание тапа при нажатии на `View` лежащие поверх?

Answer (score 1):

Назначьте Ваш контроллер делегатом `UITapGestureRecognizer`

```
viewTap.delegate = self
```

и проверяйте где происходит нажатие:

```
extension ViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        return touch.view == view
    }
}
```

Comment: Кажись вы совсем не поняли мой вопрос или я его не правильно сформулировал

Comment: @Daniyal1909 тогда распишите подробнее, приложите пример проекта где необходимо решить проблему..

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить у view, которые должны быть неактивными, свойство .isUserInteractionEnabled в false

Comment: При добавлении такого параметра отключеются все тапы поверх вьюшки(кликабельная часть попапа отключится), а не те которые ниже

Comment: Если честно, то когда я делал вьюшку для попапов, я использовал отдельный вью с блюр-эффектом. На вью с блюр-эфектом уже накладывал вью с попапом. Так проще и смотрится симпатично (затемняется нижний вью и становится неактивным, а также подчеркивается показ попапа). В крайнем случае добавь вью с прозрачным цветом под попап и не заморачивайся с обратной активацией кнопок и распознавателей движений на корневом вью

Comment: а как насчет сделать отдельный ViewController и настроить его показ как поповер?)